# NodeJS/Express routing breaking static files when url is followed by /

Tags: node.js, express

I have my static files set up like so:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I can load the page 'mysite.com/test' correctly using:

```
app.route('/test')
   .get(function(req,res){
       res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html') 
      //Actually in my model it uses res.render('pugfile.pug') rather than send, but I don't see why that would make a difference.
})
```

However if I were to load the page 'mysite.com/test/', it still loads the html, but **not** the static files.

Same problem occurs if I'm trying to navigate to any pages that are multiple division deep eg 'mysite.com/test/test/test'. The html loads fine, but not the static files. I thought the whole point of the express static middleware was to cope with this issue.

It seems like something obvious that I've missed here.

Comment: try to add ./ before public app.use(express.static('./public'); if it works, I'll explain in an answer

Comment: What is the content of `index.html`? My guess is you're using relative paths that evaluate incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah, its clearly a pathing issue, but I thought the whole point of the express static middleware was to cope with that? the css in the html file (for example) is just simply <link href='styles/css/stylesheet.css' type='text/CSS' rel='stylesheet' />

Comment: Adding ./ before public didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

You need to add / to the front of all the static files you want to work apparently.

```
<link href='styles/css/stylesheet.css' type='text/CSS' rel='stylesheet' />
```

changes to

```
<link href='/styles/css/stylesheet.css' type='text/CSS' rel='stylesheet' />
```